# jest enzyme test method in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to test a method has been called in componentDidMount:

```
private timerToken;

public componentDidMount() {
    this.timerToken = setInterval(() => { this._getWebJobStatus(); }, 2000);
}

test("_getWebJobStatus() is called", () => {
        const spy = jest.spyOn(UploadStatus.prototype, "componentDidMount").mockReturnThis();
        const wrapper = mount(<testComponent />);
        const component = wrapper.instance() as testComponent;
        const _getWebJobStatusMock = jest.fn();
        component['timerToken'] = _getWebJobStatusMock;
        expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);   // this works
        expect(_getWebJobStatusMock).toHaveBeenCalled();   //this is not working
    });
```

How do I test _getWebJobStatus() is called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Jest has nice support for testing Timer functions. You can test your code following way:

```
jest.useFakeTimers();

describe("Component", () => {
    const getComponent = () => shallow(<Component />);

    it('should call setInterval on mounting', () => {
        const component = getComponent();

        expect(setInterval).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expect.any(Function), 1000);
    });
});
```

Documentation around this can be found here: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/timer-mocks.html
P.S. Avoid using mount or render offered by enzyme whenever possible, shallow is faster than rest two and hence it reduces time required to run your test suite.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same you way you do it with `componentDidMount`. Like this:

```
test('_getWebJobStatus() is called', () => {  
  const componentDidMountSpy = jest.spyOn(UploadStatus.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
  const componentGetWebJobStatusMock = jest.spyOn(UploadStatus.prototype, '_getWebJobStatus');

  const wrapper = Enzyme.shallow(<UploadStatus/>);

  expect(UploadStatus.prototype.componentDidMount).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(UploadStatus.prototype._getWebJobStatus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

  componentDidMountSpy.mockClear();
  componentGetWebJobStatusMock.mockClear();
});
```

Comment: Your mock clearance calls (`mockClear()`) at the end are useless, because failed `expect` will return function immediately. These calls should be separated from test, somewhere in a teardown part.